# Docker - sharing layers between images

Tags: docker

I downloaded two images and the sizes are as follows :

```
openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin   latest                       9a0491580442        16 months ago       4.89GB
bde2020/spark-worker                    2.4.0-hadoop2.8              a00ffe532f34        19 months ago       3.29GB
```

The image `openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin` uses `bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.8` as the base image.

I am under impression that these images must be sharing common layers, so that total size should be 4.89GB or almost 8GB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, same layers are "shared".
Docker using hashes (including filesystem and commands) to identify these layers.

So docker shows you the size of the images (including the base-images) but that doesn't mean that they needs the same disk space.

Comment: so you mean the total occupied size might not be 8 GB ?

Comment: Yes. You see it when you download images with same the same base-image. Docker will skip existing layers.

Comment: If openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin is indeed built on top of bde2020/spark-worker, yes. The size displayed by `docker image ls` is the cumulative size of all layers. But I believe these two images have no layer in common.

Comment: The image openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin uses bde2020/spark-worker as the base image. That way, openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin must be "sharing" the same image, though the entries shown differently "docker image ls"

Comment: @Nag, your assumption is incorrect. The two images are not derived one from the other. I'll be explaining in 1 minute in an answer.

Comment: sure, please also provide details wrt layers ( layer ids ) . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The size displayed by `docker image ls` is the cumulative sum of all the image's underlying layers.

One layer(identified by its sha256) is only stored once on the disk. You may compare the image with an object that has multiple references(*shortcuts*) to the real layers that are stored on the disk. Therefore, if two images are sharing layers, those shared layers do not count twice in the disk space economy, hence they're read-only.

You can check the layers that compose an image yourself under `RootFS.Layers`:

```
docker image inspect bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.8
...
"Layers": [
                "sha256:6b3f8ebf864ca8318043df199cfadafff30d4b7cd36fced3e8aa70a318a7ee7d",
                "sha256:402964b3d72ec5114e2f5a33d6f66ebec713b480b7e2eefe76316ea2716bb7b3",
                "sha256:9ab7eda5c826e4a810db57b848abef1aa507fc9739fcdb2b1e5ce59c32013a36",
                "sha256:9752c15164a87bb763f8c98594cd5f6fb1f7bfc1a345ea8d9d3cd7613b5af633",
                "sha256:f231cc200afe521444a90bdfbffb749158db7e2b7ee3b5db4f506e045732fa3d",
                "sha256:3df7be72984142742041d406d9a87e441c451a43b1b542fa04ac868651ef4270",
                "sha256:ae150883d6e23a3226361215b17132fa700296c9f3412c47122672ddb9bf6e8a",
                "sha256:aebfac95d831e52065bccfa8bff39274c6b8d6cf1ad6aa3dfe5e14f6ead25162",
                "sha256:44a0f5b45b77371e6ff5f2edb324866162a43c738906a27e6cee1dc83afd2a3d",
                "sha256:d469bcc2e5f63e2a595619d47126e4d34a8bd6ce7ef1f2aa159e7ae6b6913b25",
                "sha256:a88264111d7623ac62661e52fc3c9f5ea2a0abe1a76de6e8731badc911a77e54",
                "sha256:d6907de311c079af9a86ccc0a50faf3a9a093a6ddce723b42a381e86433be678",
                "sha256:702aa174263c14579400c326ed4b702087ae0762340286e0ef0350f5204ebb85",
                "sha256:a922bbe2853a6127aede4bcf6265db0020898334bed465ead0943c77db0b0a53",
                "sha256:16946f8b44a62aa237a0f982cdddf4d4c5076c108549c24bf8ff0ff7b33dc0de",
                "sha256:47f41289787d8bc23dc61b37b01f28dafa1cf1ad64b62f92d22d32ac48c3318a",
                "sha256:0e2def866256c9f461ee1f48a0b196a7550baf30160effeec83a1118cc9c3523",
                "sha256:12f3bd1236457e184de023b8554743ab86b84ae52213f52ddae1d00aded4a466",
                "sha256:134803d05af38d1097fe267fabafe3e2191de062c9f3e8814eee9fb662276490",
                "sha256:e1a5cad78cb9325a0d59b594b8956d66678357be7d381209e4f65ed84d183d1b",
                "sha256:9defc18a7278f6278c65281168d291723f5aaa8a3bb03c979f3c33d6666753a2",
                "sha256:0df1dbc5aaf2836ad0df46d53cdee4b2607287cb1c3321703f4e94a678869bf5",
                "sha256:7edc1cd579415076fab31f7ee0d4e7d656469e25dea76bd5aaf6c9705c7e4b99",
                "sha256:243c0e51121befddeef9c1bf096de03d4f280c98102130fb9a969f6e009914b7",
                "sha256:b3e2729e751313d03de1bc981363e31523982740fd670d7cb90222f00477cf8e",
                "sha256:2deb24b174cdd510d7fb4b66ee1b7d539a3f51287091fb3af14806c9d66a4e4d",
                "sha256:c9519bb4cbec339b1c4da93ebf8ec010ba7467b1274d89d6f7c34091b97a1f39",
                "sha256:1838afe4041e2e3a0874541d9c245e81176483275b9228f5be626355987eb536",
                "sha256:05727ed881eab7e8c276adcef34a573281c62edf3745e385ad7a127a3a93836e",
                "sha256:dd2c90fe36d9976cc33e1641d3870d5259207defc71121ad43334286e92c811f",
                "sha256:4be9d045f56c3389c9fed187035f9dad7e5ff3c2f7ea58927641589dfca61c99",
                "sha256:b3b95d836b240eb8d70b5f063ff185392be5b0e2dc53870ff7978e863c71cb8e",
                "sha256:305d71176c6a4e132381c95218051e21b8b5e9b8149b6a9a41b280389e8d09cd",
                "sha256:b98b3f11d64d5896beab197e5632b9ace49d4342ece1712d86353240791b1cc9"
            ]
...

docker image inspect openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin
...
"Layers": [
                "sha256:6b3f8ebf864ca8318043df199cfadafff30d4b7cd36fced3e8aa70a318a7ee7d",
                "sha256:402964b3d72ec5114e2f5a33d6f66ebec713b480b7e2eefe76316ea2716bb7b3",
                "sha256:9ab7eda5c826e4a810db57b848abef1aa507fc9739fcdb2b1e5ce59c32013a36",
                "sha256:9752c15164a87bb763f8c98594cd5f6fb1f7bfc1a345ea8d9d3cd7613b5af633",
                "sha256:f231cc200afe521444a90bdfbffb749158db7e2b7ee3b5db4f506e045732fa3d",
                "sha256:3df7be72984142742041d406d9a87e441c451a43b1b542fa04ac868651ef4270",
                "sha256:ae150883d6e23a3226361215b17132fa700296c9f3412c47122672ddb9bf6e8a",
                "sha256:aebfac95d831e52065bccfa8bff39274c6b8d6cf1ad6aa3dfe5e14f6ead25162",
                "sha256:44a0f5b45b77371e6ff5f2edb324866162a43c738906a27e6cee1dc83afd2a3d",
                "sha256:d469bcc2e5f63e2a595619d47126e4d34a8bd6ce7ef1f2aa159e7ae6b6913b25",
                "sha256:a88264111d7623ac62661e52fc3c9f5ea2a0abe1a76de6e8731badc911a77e54",
                "sha256:d6907de311c079af9a86ccc0a50faf3a9a093a6ddce723b42a381e86433be678",
                "sha256:702aa174263c14579400c326ed4b702087ae0762340286e0ef0350f5204ebb85",
                "sha256:a922bbe2853a6127aede4bcf6265db0020898334bed465ead0943c77db0b0a53",
                "sha256:16946f8b44a62aa237a0f982cdddf4d4c5076c108549c24bf8ff0ff7b33dc0de",
                "sha256:47f41289787d8bc23dc61b37b01f28dafa1cf1ad64b62f92d22d32ac48c3318a",
                "sha256:0e2def866256c9f461ee1f48a0b196a7550baf30160effeec83a1118cc9c3523",
                "sha256:12f3bd1236457e184de023b8554743ab86b84ae52213f52ddae1d00aded4a466",
                "sha256:134803d05af38d1097fe267fabafe3e2191de062c9f3e8814eee9fb662276490",
                "sha256:e1a5cad78cb9325a0d59b594b8956d66678357be7d381209e4f65ed84d183d1b",
                "sha256:9defc18a7278f6278c65281168d291723f5aaa8a3bb03c979f3c33d6666753a2",
                "sha256:0df1dbc5aaf2836ad0df46d53cdee4b2607287cb1c3321703f4e94a678869bf5",
                "sha256:7edc1cd579415076fab31f7ee0d4e7d656469e25dea76bd5aaf6c9705c7e4b99",
                "sha256:243c0e51121befddeef9c1bf096de03d4f280c98102130fb9a969f6e009914b7",
                "sha256:b3e2729e751313d03de1bc981363e31523982740fd670d7cb90222f00477cf8e",
                "sha256:2deb24b174cdd510d7fb4b66ee1b7d539a3f51287091fb3af14806c9d66a4e4d",
                "sha256:c9519bb4cbec339b1c4da93ebf8ec010ba7467b1274d89d6f7c34091b97a1f39",
                "sha256:1838afe4041e2e3a0874541d9c245e81176483275b9228f5be626355987eb536",
                "sha256:05727ed881eab7e8c276adcef34a573281c62edf3745e385ad7a127a3a93836e",
                "sha256:dd2c90fe36d9976cc33e1641d3870d5259207defc71121ad43334286e92c811f",
                "sha256:4be9d045f56c3389c9fed187035f9dad7e5ff3c2f7ea58927641589dfca61c99",
                "sha256:b3b95d836b240eb8d70b5f063ff185392be5b0e2dc53870ff7978e863c71cb8e",
                "sha256:305d71176c6a4e132381c95218051e21b8b5e9b8149b6a9a41b280389e8d09cd",
                "sha256:b98b3f11d64d5896beab197e5632b9ace49d4342ece1712d86353240791b1cc9",
                "sha256:89ae73266e33dfd0eb7874f1b6b5d4f1fef2e9c8a25904f0b2c0a68a3e6f6419",
                "sha256:6375bbfba5904c6aa452e160408d36c323e772ea4de4faa60d6f7ca74db522d4",
                "sha256:d64c48e05f8e3fdfd5fe10bbfffb28c7d0d827816ebe83b924f69bd932c85867",
                "sha256:64fdd93c1a37069f14dbdf87f3906aed05a41dbd2d6130c00b316c46312b1e87",
                "sha256:44927f232ad07125b2a7dd3f539fe9c38e33c78f27c48e30b840a17b8758353b"
            ]
...
```

As you can see, some of the layers are shared, meaning those will only count once, although the images don't take this into account in the size that is displayed by `docker image ls`

Comment: hmm, please check this - bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.8 . You must be seeing common layers

Comment: You are actually correct, but the images what you mentioned are different, openkbs/docker-spark-bde2020-zeppelin uses bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.8 as the base image. So , I am under impression that they must be sharing some common layers .

Comment: @Nag you're right. I just pulled the image with the tag you mentioned and it has multiple layers in common with the zeppelin image. I'll update the answer

Comment: Great. Thanks. It provided lots of insights, though some misunderstanding :-)